# "Missing \endcsname inserted" error after \expandafter chain

Tags: expansion, csname

## Solved

Thanks to @PhelypeOleinik for the solution! And thanks to everyone else who responded so quickly to provide assistance. For anyone who finds this post in the future, the error really had nothing to do with ConTeXt, so the explanation below will be useful even if you use LaTeX or plain TeX.

## Original Post

I am creating a module in ConTeXt that is primarily accessed through a command `\setup<name>[]` (for some generic structure named `<name>`). Apart from this and a few other commands intended for the end-user, I have been adding a namespace prefix to all my internal commands, but due to how I want this command to operate, I chose not to use ConTeXt's built-in `\installcommandhandler`.

Nonetheless, I have almost finished the entire thing except for one incredibly irritating namespace-related bug that I haven't been able to work out. At one point, one of my commands calls `\processcommacommand[<list>]<command>` where both `<list>` and `<command>` are in `\csname` style, due to namespace prefixing, and both need to be expanded with `\expandafter` chains. I've isolated the problematic section and changed command names below:

```
\unprotect

\installnamespace{nms}
%\def\????nms{@@@@nms} % For testing only
% A simpler namespace creator could just run e.g. \def\????nms{@@@@nms}, but since in
% practice the actual namespace installer won't determine the prefix string until runtime,
% I have to define everything as generally as possible below, in terms of
% \csname\????nms<other>\endcsname.

% ... other module code ...

% If #1 consists of <arg1A>,<arg1B>,... separated by commas, and #2 consists of
% <arg2Akey>=<arg2Aval>, <arg2Bkey>=<arg2Bval>,... separated by commas, the
% \<namespace>_processor command below attempts to create a series of commands like so:
% % \def\<namespace>@<tag>@<arg1A>@<arg2Akey>{arg2Aval}
% % \def\<namespace>@<tag>@<arg1B>@<arg2bkey>{arg2Bval}
% % etc.
% ...for some externally defined string \tag.

\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter\def\csname\????nms _processor\endcsname[#1][#2]{%
    \expandafter\def\csname\????nms _params\endcsname##1{%
        \doifnotempty{##1}{\getparameters[\????nms @\tag @##1@][#2]}
    }
    \expandafter\def\csname\????nms _csvs\endcsname{#1}
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\processcommacommand\expandafter\expandafter
        \expandafter[\expandafter\csname\????nms _csvs\endcsname\expandafter]%
        \csname\????nms _params\endcsname
    % The above should simplify to
    % % \processcommacommand[\<namespace>_csvs]\<namespace>_params,
    % ...but in practice it throws a "Missing \endcsname inserted" error.
}

% ... other module code ...

\protect
\endinput
```

However, if I set the namespace at the top to be defined by `\def\????nms{@@@@nms}` instead and replace the problematic line, which begins with the 3 `\expandafter` calls, with direct references to the namespace prefix (e.g. `\processcommacommand[\@@@@nms_csvs]\@@@@nms_params`), the entire module works just fine, which is baffling to me, since this shouldn't be any different in theory. Am I using `\expandafter` incorrectly? I tried rewriting that particular line a few times and it came out the exact same way, so I can't tell what mistakes, if any, I'm making there.

Comment: I get no error with your code above.

Comment: Could the error be caused by something in the rest of the code, then? I keep getting the same error with this same code that seems to work for you, and I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: Is your context up-to-date? Can you show the log-file of the code above?

Comment: The log file shows `ConTeXt  ver: 2018.07.02 14:39 MKIV beta  fmt: 2018.9.17  int: english/english` for my version. I'm a bit wary of posting the entire log file due to privacy concerns (and probably some paranoia), but I'll add the specific error message to the original post. Let me know if I'm leaving out anything essential.

Comment: My context is newer.

Comment: I don't know about ConTeXt, but your last `\expandafter`y is wrong. The correct way would be: `\expandafter\processcommacommand\expandafter[\csname\????nms _csvs\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter]\csname\????nms _params\endcsname`. Try with this to see if it works.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Actually that does work as long as I don't add a line break after the closing bracket. Thanks for the help! Why doesn't it work in the original instance, though? Something to do with how \expandafter works on \endcsname?

Comment: @G.S. If you add a line break, the `\expandafter` will expand the implicit space token after the `]`. If you add a `%` after the `]` the line break will also work. Do you want an answer explaining the `\expandafter`y?

Comment: Yeah I was talking more about the `\expandafter` chain, but any information is welcome, really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in the comments, I'm the Jon Snow of ConTeXt, so this answer is about the `\expandafter` chain.

The first `\expandafter`s you used are correct. The last one is the problem:

```
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\processcommacommand\expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter[\expandafter\csname\????nms _csvs\endcsname\expandafter]
    \csname\????nms _params\endcsname
```

Let's walk through it. The first chain expands the highlighted tokens:

[image]

So the first chain expanded onlt `\????nms` and stopped, so we are left with:

```
\expandafter\processcommacommand\expandafter
    [\csname<\????nms>_csvs\endcsname\expandafter]
    \csname\????nms _params\endcsname
```

where `<\????nms>` denotes one expansion of `\????nms`. Let's say that `\????nms` expands to `NMS`, just for the example.

Then, the second chain:

[image]

expands the `\csname NMS_csvs\endcsname` and stops, now we're left with:

```
\processcommacommand
    [\NMS_csvs\expandafter]
    \csname\????nms _params\endcsname
```

And the next thing executed is `\processcommacommand` with some strange arguments. Not what we wanted.

A correct `\expandafter` chain would be:

```
\expandafter\processcommacommand\expandafter
  [\csname\????nms _csvs\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter]%
   \csname\????nms _params\endcsname
```

but why?

Firstly, you *don't need* to expand things inside a `\csname...\endcsname`. The `\csname` primitive performs full expansion of everything until the next `\endcsname`, so:

```
\def\my{MY}
\def\cmd{COMMAND}
\expandafter\def\csname\my\cmd\endcsname{Hello}
\MYCOMMAND
```

works with only one `\expandafter`.

So in your code you only need to expand both `\csname`s, and they will expand `\????nms` when needed.

Second (and consequence of the first), is that you can "continue" an `\expandafter` chain from inside a `\csname` (it performs full expansion, remember?). So `\csname\expandafter\endcsname\hello` will expand `\hello` before the `\csname`.

Now, writing it down. We start with:

```
\processcommacommand
  [\csname\????nms _csvs\endcsname]%
   \csname\????nms _params\endcsname
```

First, we expand the first `\csname`. Only two `\expandafter`s are needed:

```
\expandafter\processcommacommand\expandafter
  [\csname\????nms _csvs\endcsname]%
   \csname\????nms _params\endcsname
```

the first will skip `\processcommacommand`, and the second will skip `[`. Now we're in a full expansion context inside the `\csname`. We can exploit this to expand the next `\csname` by inserting one `\expandafter` right before `\endcsname` and continuing the chain from here:

```
\expandafter\processcommacommand\expandafter
  [\csname\????nms _csvs\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter]%
   \csname\????nms _params\endcsname
```

the first `\expandafter` will skip the `\endcsname`, and the next will skip the `]`.

Comment: Absolutely beautiful. I can't thank you enough for taking the time to put this together.

However, I'd like to clarify something about my original (incorrect) thought process: I didn't put `\expandafter` calls inside the brackets because I thought it would expand `\????nms`. I expected TeX to make two passes over the statement and thought that `\expandafter` would skip over everything from `\csname` to `\endcsname`, leaving it for the next pass.

Comment: @G.S. Ooh, I understand it now. It could've worked, but `\expandafter` skips exactly _one_ token regardless of what that is. It can be even a `{` or a `}`. Your first `\csname...\endcsname` consists of 8 tokens! For your approach work you would need to expand the `\csname` first, then TeX would turn the eight tokens into one single control sequence token, which could then be skipped by another `\expandafter` chain. But then you can exploit the full expansion and do everything in one go. Glad you liked it :)